# Redshift Spectrum gives syntax error on creating nested data

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, amazon-redshift-spectrum

I am using this query

```sql
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE test.post(
      edge_media_to_tagged_user struct<
            "edges": array<
            "node": struct<
                "user": struct<
                  id:bigint,
                  username:text
                >,
                x: float(24),
                y: float(24)
            >
        >
      >
  )
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'
LOCATION 's3://bucket/test';
```

Somehow the query above gives me

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near ":"
LINE 4:             "node": struct<
```

Removing or adding colon and/or double quote still gives me the error.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Answer from John](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56694935/1780570) gives an important hint, this code work

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE likes_schema_test.post88(
      edge_media_to_tagged_user struct<
        "edges": array<struct<      <-- change here
            "node": struct<
                "user": struct<
                  full_name:text,
                  id:bigint,
                  is_verified: boolean,
                  username:text
                >,
                x: float(24),
                y: float(24)
            >>
        >
      >
  )
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'
LOCATION 's3://follower-dumper-testing/post_test';
```

Changing `"node"` to `'node'` would give a syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say it's probably being caused by this bit:

```
        "edges": array<
        "node": struct<
```

An array does not contain named items, so it is probably failing when it discovers `"node":` inside the `array` definition.

Answer (score -1):

Redshift unfortunately does not support the struct data type. The complete list of data types that Redshift supports can be found [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_Supported_data_types.html).

EDIT: *Normal* Redshift doesn't support structs. Redshift Spectrum does.

Comment: Redshift Spectrum does, according to https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c-spectrum-external-tables.html

Comment: Ah I see. Looks like this link says that Redshift supports single quotes, not double: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c-spectrum-troubleshooting.html

Comment: I have just learned that single quote is for `LOCATION` and `ROW FORMAT`, see my answer for more details

Comment: Glad you got it working. Thank you for introducing to me to Spectrum, this was the first I had heard of it!

Comment: You are very welcome! Note that there is a difference between Redshift and Redshift Spectrum. One is a version of Postgres in the cloud and one is a tool to parse JSON from S3.

Comment: Yes I looked into the pricing difference and I am hesitant to switch. Still waiting to do performance tests before deciding. Very cool feature though!